# API Яндекс диска

Tags: java, yandex-disk

Я отправляю запрос на https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/v1/disk/resources?path=%2F и сюда нужно привязать 
отправку токена для подтверждения. Реализую я это с помощью

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth 0c4181a7c2cf4521964a72ff57a34a07");
```

Но почему то выводит: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/v1/disk/resources?path=%2F

```
public String stringUrlRequesDowload( ){
    String response = "";
    BufferedInputStream buffer=null; 
    HttpURLConnection connection=null; 
    String urlRequest = "https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/v1/disk/resources?path=%2F";
    try {
        URL ur=new URL(urlRequest); 
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) ur.openConnection(); 
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth 0c4181a7c2cf4521964a72ff57a34a07");
        buffer=new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());    
        connection.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(response);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Второй "/resources" в запросе не лишний?

Comment: Лишний) Исправил

Answer (score 1):

Судя по url https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/resources?path=%2F вы пытаетесь просмотреть список файлов в директории.

Судя по документации, случае ошибки в теле ответа с сервера вернется json объект с пояснением:

> **Ошибка при обработке запроса**
>
> Ошибка может произойти, если запрос составлен некорректно, указанный ресурс отсутствует на сервере, сервер неработоспособен и т. п. Все ошибки возвращаются с соответствующими кодами HTTP-ответа. Все возможные коды ответа и пояснения к ним приведены на Полигоне (чтобы увидеть их, разверните нужный запрос и нажмите ссылку Показать рядом с заголовком Сообщения ответа).
>
> Дополнительно ошибки описываются JSON-объектом, например:
>
> ```
> {
>   "description": "resource already exists",
>   "error": "PlatformResourceAlreadyExists"
> }
> ```

Для более детальной информации предлагаю обратиться к документации [REST API Яндекс Диска](https://tech.yandex.ru/disk/api/reference/meta-docpage/)

Answer (score 0):

Вы подключаетесь по http протоколу (HttpURLConnection) вместо https, поэтому и получаете 405 ошибку

Вот код, который работает

```
    URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
    HttpsURLConnection httpsConn = (HttpsURLConnection) urlConn;
    httpsConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpsConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth 0c4181a7c2cf4521964a72ff57a34a07");
    httpsConn.connect();
    int resCode = httpsConn.getResponseCode();
```