# Yandex disk api парсинг

Tags: java, yandex-disk

Попытался для начала получить список файлов с помощью [Яндекс диск полигон](https://tech.yandex.ru/disk/poligon/#!//v1/disk/resources/GetLastUploadedFilesList).
Тут у меня три проблемы:

- во первых фильтрация параметров не работает
- во вторых в ответе я получаю тарабарщину вместо русских букв
- в третьих мне бы совет как парсить ответ, а то я пока только читать его могу

Код:

```
public static String stringUrlRequesDowload( ) {
    String response = "";
    BufferedInputStream buffer=null; 
    String urlRequest = "https://cloud-api.yandex.net:443/v1/disk/resources/last-uploaded?fields=name&limit=100";
    try {
        URL url=new URL(urlRequest); 
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
        HttpsURLConnection httpsConn = (HttpsURLConnection) urlConn;
        httpsConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpsConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "мойтокен");
        buffer=new BufferedInputStream(httpsConn.getInputStream());    
        File file =new File("cashe");
        int c=0;
        while((c=buffer.read())!=-1) {
            response=response+(char)c;
        }
        int resCode = httpsConn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(resCode);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(response);
    return response;
}
```

Результат слишком длинный.

PS использую Eclipse Oxygen

Comment: Рыбу за вас тут ловить не будут, и даже удочку не дадут, но вот чертежи удочки - это можно. Как минимум Вам надо знать, как на `Java` делать `GET` и `POST` `HTTP` запросы, а также парсить `JSON`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [API Яндекс диска](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471581/api-%d0%af%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, почему ссылка выше "API Яндекс диска" вам не помогла.

Comment: что полигон что программа игнорирует параметры в поле fields